# Durandal dialog

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Please help. I'm trying to create a knockout template for durandal's dialog plugin. Is there anyone who can give me a basic example for this. Below is my sample code. But I can't make it work..

```
(function (require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app'),
    unitofwork = require('services/unitofwork'),
    dialog = require('plugins/dialog');


    var self = this;
    var uow = unitofwork.create();
    var userlist = ko.observableArray();
    var selecteduser = ko.observable();

    ko.dialog = {
    // Defines a view model class you can use to populate a grid

        viewModel: {
            selecteduser: selecteduser,
            userlist: userlist,
            ok: function () {
                console.log(this.selecteduser());
                dialog.close(this, this.selecteduser());
            },
            cancel: function () {
                console.log(this.selecteduser());
                dialog.close(this, "");
            },
            canDeactivate: function () {
                return dialog.showMessage(this.selecteduser());
            },
            show: function () {
                var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                                    .from("GetUsersByRole")
                                    .withParameters({ roleName: "EDITOR" }); // id=3 has two UserRoles

                uow.userrepository.CustomQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                    userlist(data);
                });

                console.log(userlist);

                return dialog.show(this);
            }
        }
    };

    // Templates used to render the grid
    var templateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();

    templateEngine.addTemplate = function (templateName, templateMarkup) {
        document.write("<script type='text/html' id='" + templateName + "'>" + templateMarkup + "<" + "/script>");
    };

    templateEngine.addTemplate("ko_dialog_dialog", "\
                    <div class=\"messageBox\">\
                        <div class=\"modal-header\">\
                            <h3>\Assign to Editor</h3>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class=\"modal-body\">\
                            <form data-bind=\"submit: ok\">\
                                <label>\
                                    Editor Name:<br />\
                                    <select id=\"selCaseStatus\"\
                                        class=\"span2 shadow_select\"\
                                        data-bind=\"value: selecteduser, options: userlist, optionsText: 'UserName', optionsValue: 'UserName', optionsCaption: '--select--'\">\
                                    </select>\
                                </label>\
                            </form>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class=\"modal-footer\">\
                            <button class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-bind=\"click: ok\">\Ok&nbsp;<i class=\"icon-thumbs-up\">\</i>\</button>\
                            <button class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-bind=\"click: cancel\">\Cancel&nbsp;<i class=\"icon-thumbs-down\">\</i>\</button>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>"
                );

    // The "dialog" binding
    ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
        init: function () {
            return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
        },
        // This method is called to initialize the node, and will also be called again if you change what the grid is bound to
        update: function (element, viewModelAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var viewModel = viewModelAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

            // Empty the element
            while (element.firstChild)
                ko.removeNode(element.firstChild);

            // Allow the default templates to be overridden
            var panelTemplateName = allBindings.leftPanelTemplate || "ko_dialog_dialog";
            //,pageLinksTemplateName = allBindings.simpleGridPagerTemplate || "ko_simpleGrid_pageLinks";

            // Render the main grid
            var panelContainer = element.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
            ko.renderTemplate(panelTemplateName, viewModel, { templateEngine: templateEngine }, panelContainer, "replaceNode");
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 8):

Durandal already has the features you're looking for, so there's no need to invent something on your own. Start reading http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html. Examples for OOTB usage can be found the the samples section e.g. http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#modal

For further customization take a look at 
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#module/dialog/method/addContext.

And finally here's what @EisenbergEffect has to say about creating new dialog templates:

> Create a new .html view in your project that contains the message box
>   markup that you want. Then, either in main.js or in your shell, before
>   you use the message box. Call
>   dialog.MessageBox.setViewUrl('path/to/your/view');

Comment: your answer is great with the fiddle to back it up - if I were you I would consider editing the question to improve the 'SEO' value of it for other users.

Comment: @PWKad What would you suggest?

Comment: Your link to the showing message box and modals has been moved to: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html

Comment: Is Rob's quote still valid?  I'm trying to set the template of the dialog from within a viewmodel (home.js, for example) - is requiring dialog still the proper way to do this?