# Displaying html and/or images in a durandal (or maybe bootstrap) dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a simple dialog using `app.showMessage(...)` and it seems that this can only display text and not html?

I'm passing in

```
"This is a lot of text that I want displaying at the top of the modal dialog.  This should be followed by an image below.<div><img src='../../Content/images/materialDimensions.jpg' /></div>"
```

But the modal dialog simply shows the text/code and not the actual image.

Is there any way to tell Durandal to change the way it binds or is it not designed this way?  Would I have to use a bootstrap modal instead?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311914/durandal-dialog

Comment: Yes, kind of thanks. It's allowed me to build up a custom dialog that pretty much does what I want.